# How do I disable assets caching in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I'm writing my first Yii2 application and I want to disable the assets caching, while I'm developing.

Can I disable the caching using the ./config/ .php files?

Comment: So you are using Yii or Yii2?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**1)** Globally it's possible with help of [AssetMananer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html). There is special option [$forceCopy](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$forceCopy-detail) for this.

You can set it like this with component:

```
use Yii;

Yii::$app->assetManager->forceCopy = true;
```

Or in application config:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
        'forceCopy' => true,          
    ],
],
```

**2)** If you want disable caching in specific [AssetBundle](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html), use [$publishOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html#$publishOptions-detail) property:

```
public $sourcePath = '...' // In order to use $publishOptions you should specify correct source path.

public $publishOptions = [
    'forceCopy' => true,
];
```

Alternatively you can specify this like in option 1 with help of [bundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$bundles-detail) property. For example:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
        'forceCopy' => true,          
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                'forceCopy' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

But this:

```
'forceCopy' => YII_DEBUG,
```

is more flexible, because it disables this asset bundle caching only in debug mode, but allows on production server. `YII_DEBUG` is set in `web/index.php`.

Comment: Strange. I've added `'authManager' => [ 'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager', 'forceCopy' => true, ],` in `'components'` (console.php and web.php), but it still caches in `web/assets`.

Comment: Disabling in this context means that folder also will be presented in assets, but on every page load its content will be forcibly copied, so it will always contain the actual versions of the files. If you don't want that, take a look at this methods. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJs%28%29-detail, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile%28%29-detail. Official documentation recommends using assets instead.

Comment: May be `assetManager` instead `authManager`?