# Javascript in Yii2 AssetBundle is not published on update

Tags: javascript, yii2, assets, assetbundle

I have a quite simple AssetBundle:

```
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * ImagizerAsset
 */
class ImagizerAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@app/components/widgets/imagizer/assets';

    public $css = [
        'css/imagizer.css'
    ];

    public $js = [
        'js/imagizer.js',
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'app\assets\BowerCropperAsset'
    ];
}
```

If I change the JavaScript in the bundle, it is not published to the web/asset directory in development mode. I must remove the web/asset directory every time to have an up to date version in it. It is very annoying. What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable assets caching in Yii2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040018/how-do-i-disable-assets-caching-in-yii2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040018/how-do-i-disable-assets-caching-in-yii2/28040671#28040671).

Add this to your asset bundle:

```
public $publishOptions = [
    'forceCopy' => YII_DEBUG,
];
```

For more options and detailed explanation look at linked answer.

Comment: I woud advise linking this to the environment, you really don't want it to be done every time. `'forceCopy' => YII_ENV === 'dev'` and you always forget to comment those out when you commit...

Comment: @Blizz It's mentioned in linked answer.

Comment: @Blizz Added it here too.